# Can kids between the age 12 to 15 years old who missed suhoor fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

What if you are between the age of 12 to 15 and you want to fast but you missed sehri. Can you still fast?

Also, if you are 12 years old, can you eat like a peach or some kind of fruit and drink a glass of water and still fast the rest of the day ?

Answer (score 3):

If the kid has reached puberty then he/she should not eat or drink anything until Maghrib Athan.

The age when someone reaches puberty differs from one person to another. For example, someone living in the desert reaches puberty at the age of 9 (Our mother Aisha reached puberty when she is 9 years old)

Answer (score 1):

There's no age mentioned about those who have to fast.  But as long as you're mature and know what you're doing is good enough that fasting is prescribed upon you.

As for sehri (sahur?) it's fard even if you drink a glass of water with the intention of fasting.

The Prophet said =

> تَسَحَّرُوا فَإِنَّ فِي السَّحُورِ بَرَكَةً
>
> **Have Sahur for in Sahur there is blessing**

[[Sahih al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/32)

Comment: Could you clarify how and why sahur is fard? That hadith doesn't seem to state anything like that.

Comment: The Prophet told us to have sahur "tasaHHroo."  It's being said as an order to do something and not a suggestion.  If it was a suggestion, there would be other ahadith telling us the Prophet didn't mean it as an order but only as a recommendation i.e. prophet has to tell us it's not a command.  But since there's no other ahadith except in the manner of what we should do, it's taken as a command to do something and not disobey it.